# Problem with nested for loop with a CSV object

Tags: python, csv

Please help me guys, I have a CSV file and a list. I want to get the values of the headers of the CSV file that have the same strings that are in my list and match them inside a dictionary for each one and put them back inside a big list.

```
csvFile =  open("smallDataFile.csv", 'r')
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile)
headersList = ['census_tract', 'tow_description', 'longitude']

def read_data(csv_object = csvReader, headers = headersList):
    next(csv_object) # To skip the header line

    myList = []
    myDict = {}
    for header in headers:
        for row in csv_object:
            myDict[header] = row[headers.index(header)]
            myList.append(myDict.copy())
    print(myList)

read_data()
```

The CSV file looks like this:

```
census_tract,tow_description,longitude
47,ACCIDENT,-78.827175001441
50,STOLEN_VEHICLE,-65.827175001441
```

My EXPECTED output was:

```
[{'census_tract': '47'}, {'tow_description': 'ACCIDENT'}, {'longitude': '-78.827175001441'}, {'census_tract': '50'}, {'tow_description': 'STOLEN_VEHICLE'}, {'longitude': '-65.827175001441'} ]
```

The ACTUAL output was this:

```
[{'census_tract': '47'}, {'census_tract': '50'}]
```

My guess is that it didn't the For Loop didn't iterate through the rest of the headers in the list for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need to swap the loops and also i modified the above your code slightly

```
for row in csv_object:
    for header in headers:
        myDict[header] = row[headers.index(header)]
    myList.append(myDict.copy())  #this one must be outside the inner loop
```

output will be as you expected

Comment: WOW! THAT WAS IT???! TOOK ME 3 HOURS OF THINKING! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

I agree more with some of the above answers, but they do not produce the output you are looking for, even though I would prefer their output.

You specific output requires something like this

```
import csv
csv_file = open('small.csv', 'r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

headers = ['census_tract', 'tow_description', 'longitude']

def read_data(obj, headers):
    next(obj)
    my_list = []
    for row in obj:
        for idx, header in enumerate(headers):
            my_dict = {header: row[idx]}
            my_list.append(my_dict)

read_data(csv_reader, headers)
```

Comment: THANK U SO MUCH MAN!